Get Kile to use the newly installed LaTeX
I installed TeX Live 2024 for my Kubuntu using https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf as suggested be egreg. I did not delete the old TeX from Kubuntu and I do not want to.
I added
PATH="/opt/texbin:$PATH"
export PATH

to ~/.bashrc, which Kile seems to use.
Now I get
$ which tex
/opt/texbin/tex
$ which pdflatex
/opt/texbin/pdflatex

which seems right. But when I compile with Kile, I get the output
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd [...]
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test_tcolorbox.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test_tcolorbox.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class

What do I need to do to get Kile to use the newly installed TeX Live 2024?

it depends whether you want to keep debian's tex installed, too. if not, you need to substitute a 'dummy' package to keep apt happy. otherwise, you either need to change PATH so /opt/bin is before /usr/bin or you need to specify the full path in kile's settings for whichever compile options you use. (the former won't work if the config already specifies full paths to /usr/bin, which may be the problem you're having. the latter is also probably safer.)

@cfr: Thanks for you questions. I want to keep the old Latex and I already edited the PATH. See my updated question. I do not know how/where to configure Kile regarding this topic.

in kile's settings there's a panel where you can edit or change what the various compilation recipes do. you can specify full paths there to ensure that e.g. the quick-build option or whatever you use uses the version in /opt/bin. as a workaround, you can also specify the full path on the command line (e.g. using the konsole.part of kile which gives you a command line within the editor).

@cfr: I cannot find the settings you are talking about.

settings > configure kile > tools > build

@cfr: Right, but what then? For example, when I click on PDFLaTeX I get to change the command and the options, but not the latex installation or the environment. BUT: I just had the idea to exchange "pdflatex" with "/opt/texbin/pdflatex". Is that what you thought of?

yes, that's what I meant about specifying the full path for the commands ;).

@cfr: Ah, ok, thanks. I was searching for a "global" way to specify where Latex is installed. But now I have to prepend for each of those commands the respective path, which is a bit tiresome.

well, the alternative is to figure out how to get PATH set correctly when you open a GUI application. but it isn't necessarily a great idea to have /opt/bin before /usr/bin in general, especially given the kinds of things which often end up in /opt. (that said, I do have /usr/local/texlive/bin before /usr/bin, except for root. but I can't remember enough about debian. you can probably edit the desktop file thing, but it is sometimes hard to get that to stick. you could also look for settings in your DE, shell, X and/or wayland configs. that depends on your setup, obviously.
